# VS code Extension errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, vscode-extensions

So I opened my VS Code this evening to do some code but for some reason all the extensions are gone. I try installing them back but it still doesn't work. Error "while installing 'GitHub Copilot' extension. Please check the log for more details." It returns this:

```
2023-08-18 04:22:08.782 [error] Error scanning system extensions: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
2023-08-18 04:22:09.206 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:09.211 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:09.212 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:09.216 [error] Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions': Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:09.253 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: javascript
2023-08-18 04:22:09.253 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: typescript
2023-08-18 04:22:09.253 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: javascriptreact
2023-08-18 04:22:09.254 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: typescriptreact
2023-08-18 04:22:09.254 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: html
2023-08-18 04:22:09.254 [error] [xabikos.JavaScriptSnippets]: Unknown language in `contributes.JavaScriptSnippets.language`. Provided value: vue
2023-08-18 04:22:09.426 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:09.440 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:11.071 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:11.175 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:22:11.439 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 50ms
2023-08-18 04:22:26.528 [error] Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions': Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:23:00.184 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:23:00.240 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:23:00.240 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:23:06.733 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async H.I (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:72675)
    at async H.F (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:68306)
    at async c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:67129
    at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
    at async H.D (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:67076)
    at async H.installGalleryExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:65540)
    at async H.installFromGallery (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:64861)
2023-08-18 04:23:06.781 [error] Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions': Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async h.call (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:34:22645)
2023-08-18 04:23:06.781 [error] Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions': Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async H.I (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:72675)
    at async H.F (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:68306)
    at async c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:67129
    at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
    at async H.D (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:67076)
    at async H.installGalleryExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:65540)
    at async H.installFromGallery (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:64861)
2023-08-18 04:25:42.727 [error] Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file 'c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions'
    at p.resolve (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:39:14125)
    at async W.k (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96904)
    at async W.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:96678)
    at async m.H (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:94050)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanSystemExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:89176)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async m.scanAllExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:88838)
    at async B.scanExtensions (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:92:10907)
    at async H.I (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:72675)
    at async H.F (c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\node\sharedProcess\sharedProcessMain.js:82:68306)
    at async c:\Users\DELL G3\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
```

This error shows for all extentions I tried installing.
If any one has has a similar problem with a fix that would be great.

I reinstalled. I also restarted my PC but it didn't work.